# How to crop/zoom without rotating in Creative Studio?

Tags: photos

I use Nokia Creative Studio a lot, to crop and edit photos. However, sometimes when zooming in or out of a photo to frame it, if I don't move my fingers quite right, I end up slightly rotating the photo as well. This is annoying because it can be hard to restore the original orientation exactly. I know I can just hit Back to cancel the changes, but that's not ideal because I will then also lose any other changes I've made.

Is there any way to disable free rotating in Creative Studio so I can crop and zoom my photos without having to worry about this? Or alternatively, can I reset the photo rotation to original without cancelling other changes?

Answer (score 1):

Which version are you using because the new update to the application has solved this problem.

> **Nokia Creative Studios v5.5.3.1 – Changelog:**
>
> General stability improvements.
>
> Storage related enhancements.

[image]

Here is the [App Link](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/nokia-creative-studio/a8ddc8f6-c12c-44e6-b22e-52e2f0905f3e).

Comment: I'm using the latest version.

Comment: www.nokialumiaapplications.com/nokia-creative-studios-version-5-5-3-1/

Comment: When you use `crop + rotate` option, it allows you to crop and zoom first. There is a button in the application bar that says `rotate to right`. If you don't select that option till then the image does not rotate.

Comment: I'm not talking about the "rotate right" button. You can also rotate the image freely with your fingers, and that sometimes ends up happening when I'm zooming in or out.

Comment: I tried it in my phone. I am not able to rotate the image freely.

Comment: Really? This has been a feature of Creative Studio for a while now (a quick search shows reviews from at least a year ago mentioning the ability to straighten photos).

Comment: I can't find a way to rotate *during crop mode*